# Trouble installing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install it on RedHat, and I get

```
                * The following required packages can not be built:

                * freetype
```

How do I install the proper `libfreetype`? What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Should just be able to do `sudo yum install freetype-devel` and it will grab it for you. See this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958780/error-installing-matplotlib-python2-7-rhel-5-9

Comment: Now, when trying to install matplotlib, I get src/_png.cpp:10:20: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory

Comment: As per that post, you also need libpng. `sudo yum install libpng-devel`